# How do I view my control source tables in Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

In Access 2003 I was easily able to get to *all* the tables and edit/view data directly. However, in 2007, I'm unable to find this functionality.  I have an MDB with a form, and I can only view the main table of user input data in the Datasheet View.

I'm trying to copy a list of options (there's a lot of them) set to a Combo Box into another program, and it would be easier if I could just get to the Control Source table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to see the access objects (tables, queries, macros, forms) in the Navigation Pane on the left side of the screen.  It may be hidden in that .mdb, though.  If you create a new .mdb and a couple of tables, can you see them?

The UI's a little different and it takes some getting used to.